# Probability of 4 starters in a 7-round draft when p is not constant each round

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

There are 7 Rounds in a Little League Draft.  The probability of drafting a starter in the first three rounds is  .55.  In the 4th round, the probability of drafting a starter drops to .35.  In the 5th, 6th, and 7th rounds of the draft, the probability of drafting a starter drops to .25.

What is the probability that a team will draft at least 4 starters in this draft?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** *as I assume this is homework*

You can calculate probabilities in each round using the results from the previous round:  here are the first few parts

- First round: $Pr(1\text{ starter}) = 0.55\times 1 = 0.55$, $Pr(0\text{ starters}) = 0.45\times 1 = 0.45$
- Second round: $Pr(2\text{ starters}) = 0.55\times 0.55 = 0.3025$, $Pr(1\text{ starter}) = 0.55\times 0.45+0.45\times 0.55 = 0.495$, $Pr(0\text{ starters}) = 0.45\times 0.45 = 0.2025$
- Third round: $Pr(3\text{ starters}) = 0.55\times 0.3025 = 0.166375$, $Pr(2\text{ starters}) = 0.55\times 0.495+0.54\times 0.3025 = 0.408375$, $Pr(1\text{ starter}) = 0.55\times 0.2025+0.45\times 0.495 = 0.334125$, $Pr(0\text{ starters}) = 0.45\times 0.2025 = 0.091125$

Just keep going.  You chould get a final answer slightly more than a quarter

Comment: Henry, thank you a ton.  I just solved it.  It was a lot of fun actually.